# Rollback Netbeans IDE

Tags: netbeans, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any way to rollback the Netbeans IDE updates?
or a log on what updates were made?

i Just updated netbeans and the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> doesn't work anymore... it's really really annoying, it's been 1hr since i made the update and it's getting on my nerves...

You have to wait half second for the little window to show up (The one that shows which file or subwindow it's going to focus on) so you can switch to the last file you've been on.

If you don't wait for that window to show up, it switches to the "Navigator" subwindow, insead of the previous focused open file

[image: History PopUp Window]

It should take you to the previous file just by tapping <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>

NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 (Build 201411181905)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once a professor in college said to me "It is wise to restart"... and so i did. :(

Sorry for the useless post.